# How to solve this error during update in a CCRC view?

Tags: java, clearcase

The latest update in the CCRC client triggered the following message:

```
CRVAP0087E (conflict):  CCRC command 'Update' failed: Problems were encountered while retrieving view synchronization information and data.

ClearCase CM Server: Error: Unable to access "\rainwater\src": Permission denied.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: 1 config spec load rule problems encountered.

    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:538)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.Util.ccrcCmdStatusToWvcmException(Util.java:155)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.Util.runCommandAndCheckResults(Util.java:107)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.WebViewRefresh.run(WebViewRefresh.java:151)
    at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.doRefresh(CcFileImpl.java:240)
    at Refresh_View.main(Refresh_View.java:39)
```

What should I look for in order to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: @user486631: I took the liberty to write a question out of your initial report. If I didn't fully understood the context, feel free to edit (and to add some more information, like the context, the exact CCRC version, the version of the registry server and Vob server to which the CCRC dialogs with, ...)

Answer (score 1):

All web views in CCRC are snapshot views.
Check their config spec to see if said snapshot view refers to a directory which is no longer accessible (a bit like in [technote swg21256715](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256715))

[image: Example of config spec error in CCRC]

The question is: "what `\rainwater\src` represents for CCRC? A snapshot root directory? or the Vob rainwater and src subdirectory within that Vob?"

In the latter case, the main `CLEARCASE` group set in the CCRC preferences is probably wrong (it is the equivalent of the environment variable `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` when you are using a full ClearCase client): it must be part of the main group of the Vob (or one of its secondary groups)